# What should I learn next as a devops beginner?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, jenkins, nginx, tomcat

I'm working as a devops engineer in a big tech company (local). The technologies used here are nginx, linux, sql, redis, docker, glassfish and payara, kubernetes, tomcat, gitlab, jenkins etc. I've learnt linux and sql till date. What should I learn next? I mean the order might be important. But the important thing to note is that for example for jenkins, mostly just building jenkins is done, there's not much of other tasks. So, will it even be worth it to learn all stuffs in detail?

They're planning to use kafka after few months as well.

Answer (score 1):

What *you* should learn next is highly contextual, so I fear this question will be closed as opinion-based.
However, there are a few patterns which we tend to see, which may help you understand where you are on *your* journey *with respect to the average* DevOps figure's  career roadmap.

I propose as an answer to this question:

1. Take a look at https://roadmap.sh/devops
2. Select the items you feel you've mastered
3. **Decide whether you want to specialise or generalise**

If you want to specialise, spend time in the area where you have the most experience (maybe Design Patterns), else if you want to generalise, pick off topics that are outside of your current comfort zone.

As an example I attach a screenshot of what a a roadmap of a typical engineer might look like:

[image]

This person might decide to specialise in monitoring, or generalise by learning more in the CI/CD space.

Comment: should I follow some particular order or can start from anywhere? Would a college level course in operating systems help for devops?